# What would be the best way to organise the following associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I'm running into a brick wall here with trying to organize some models and associations with an app I'm currently working on. Any thoughts would be most welcome!

The app centers around `consultations`, `invoices` and `prescriptions`. They all will have associated `productItems` (which are essentially a combination of a product, client, quantity etc).

The consultation will invariably share the same product items as a corresponding invoice and prescription. The problem comes though as not every invoice or prescription is tied to a consultation. It's possible to have a standalone invoice or prescription.

In this case, I'm struggling to find a common "ancestor" for want of a better word, where I could keep all the shared data and then use the same reference across the different models.

As an alternative, I considered creating separate models for each association as below but then my worry would be duplication:

```
ConsultationProductItem
 - belongs_to animal
 - belongs_to product
 - belong_to consultation

InvoiceProductItem
 - belongs_to animal
 - belongs_to product
 - belong_to invoice

PrescriptionProductItem
 - belongs_to animal
 - belongs_to product
 - belong_to prescription
```

It seems flaky as these would be the same data shared across multiple models.

With the above setup, I'd also have to regularly take the various items belonging to say a consultation and copy them over to the corresponding invoice or prescription.

I feel like I'm going round in circles with this, I'm currently torn between the backend of the app being built with Rails or Meteor/Mongo, I'd feel more comfortable with rock-solid associations that Rails is normally so good at enforcing but can't seem to figure out which technique to use for it. Any thoughts much appreciated!

Edit:

I'm now wondering if I can maybe create an "ancestor" type model as below:

```
ProductGroup
  - id

Consultation
  - productGroup

Invoice
  - productGroup

Prescription
  - productGroup

ProductItem
  - belongs_to product_group
  - animal
  - product
  - quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can go for polymorphic implementation.** 
**ConsultationProductItem**

 - has_many :productItem, as: product

**InvoiceProductItem**

- has_many :productItem, as: product

**PrescriptionProductItem**

 - has_many :productItem, as: product

**ProductItem**
 - belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true

Comment: Thanks. I think polymorphic could be useful but in my case I'm going to want to use the exact same items so it wouldn't be a case of one or the other.